# Express highest floating point quantity that is less than 1

Tags: c++, c, math

I was doing some rounding calculations and happened upon a question. How can I express the highest quantity less than 1 for a given floating point type?

That is, how I write/represent value `x` such that `x < 1, x + y >= 1` for any `y > 0`.

In fractions this would be `x = (q-1)/q` where `q` is the *precision* of the type. For example, if you are counting in `1/999` increments then `x = 998/999`.

For a given type (float, double, long double), how could one express the value `x` in code?

---

I also wonder if such a value actually exists for all values of `y`. That is, as `y's` exponent gets smaller perhaps the relation doesn't hold anymore. So an answer with some range restriction on `y` is also acceptable. (The value of `x` I want still does exist, the relationship may just not properly express it.)

Comment: Are you looking for some sort of formula?  A constant?  An algorithm to find it?

Comment: A constant would be preferred, but a function would also be acceptable.

Comment: take a look at dlamch over at netlib

Answer (score 13, accepted):

C99 defines `nextafter()` function. Use it like

```
#include <math.h>
double under_one = nextafter(1, 0);
```

Comment: @Chris `1` is represented precisely in binary, so using it just like I wrote will give you largest possible "under 1" double value

Comment: Yes, that appears to be exactly what I want.  Is there any way to express this value as a constant? That is, if I wish to use it as a default parameter?

Comment: If we assume that epsilon towards 0.0 is two times finer than towards 2.0, we can use FLT_EPSILON constant, dividing it by 2.

Comment: @Chris: An implementation where 1 is not 1 is hopeless beyond all usability. C probably allows such brokenness, but there's little point in writing any floating point code at all unless you assume sanity. Personally I always assume IEEE 754 semantics and representations.

Answer (score 5):

Altouht others are right that greater value less than `1` is `1-FLT_EPSILON`, in floating point it cannot meet condition *`x < 1, x + y >= 1` for any `y > 0`*, unless you're using rounding up.

The reason is that distance between 1 and previous to it (which is `FLT_EPSILON` ~ 1.2E-7) is much greater that minimum representable positive number `FLT_MIN`, which is ~ 1.2E-38. So there exist a class of numbers (`FLT_MIN ... FLT_EPSILON/2` when rounding to nearest, which is default for most systems) for which `(1-FLT_EPSILON)+y == (1-FLT_EPSILON) < 1`.

Comment: This is also good to know. It address my concern about whether such a number is possible.

Comment: Doesn't this imply that epsilon from 1.0 towards 0.0 is FLT_EPSILON/2 ?

Comment: I do not sure this is so, but seems to be. I may be wrong in details. Range may be FLT_MIN...FLT_EPSILON/4, not /2, as it is half of actual epsilon, but it exists.

Answer (score 3):

There is a way to acquire the lowest quantity that being added to 1 would produce least expressible quantity greater than 1. That's `std::numeric_limits<type>::epsilon()`. If you prove that this quantity is equal to the one you search, that's what you want:

> template static _Tp std::numeric_limits< _Tp >::epsilon ()  throw () [inline, static]
>          The machine epsilon: the difference between 1 and the least value greater than 1 that is representable.

Comment: Is it guaranteed that `1 - epsilon + epsilon == 1`?

Comment: The answer is probably "no". I experimented with nextafter() function, trying to get the epsilon from 1.0 towards 0.0 and towards 2.0 - the results are different. Epsilon towards 2.0 is exactly two times larger than towards 0.0 - possibly because latter is expressed using the denormalized numbers, that have 1 more bit for precision.

Comment: For binary floating point, 1-epsilon will be too big.  Exemple with a FP format with 3 binary digits: the next number after 1.00 is 1.01 so epsilon is 0.01, while the number before 1.00 is 0.111.

Comment: @edA: C makes no guarantees about floating point results whatsoever. IEEE 754 of course guarantees it because all the values involved are exact.

Answer (score 2):

The IEEE 754 floating point representation has the property that for numbers which are positive and not `NaN` the order is the same as the order on the bit patterns viewed as integers.

So you can reinterpret the bit pattern of the floating point number 1.0 as an integer, decrement that integer and then reinterpret it again as a floating point number, to get the floating point number just below one.

Answer (score 1):

According to the IEEE 754 standard , single-precision (32-bit) 1.0 has the representation 0x3F800000. We can write this in binary as 0 01111111 (1)00000000000000000000000, which means:

```
sign = 0
biased exponent = 01111111 = 0x7F, so exponent = -23 (decimal)
mantissa = 0x800000 (the (1) in parentheses is the implied msb)
```

So the value is 0x800000 * 2^-23, which is 1.0. The next lowest single-precision number is

```
0 01111110 (1)11111111111111111111111
```

or 0x3F7FFFFF, or 0xFFFFFF * 2^-24, which is about 0.99999994.

Comment: AFAIK, IEEE-754 representation implies a hidden MSB always equal to 1 (unless it's a denormal number). Thus, highest quantity below 1.0 would be represented as all-ones (1) mantissa and (-1) exponent. MSB of that number would be an implied (1), so mantissa effectively receives one more bit. Thats why epsilon towards 0.0 is 2 times finer than epsilon towards 2.0.

Answer (score 1):

The `nextafter()` function works well [@qrdl](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4552647/2410359)

```
#include <math.h>
// find next double from 1.0 working towards 0.0
double before_1 = nextafter(1.0, 0.0);
```

---

Yet to do so at compile time value as commented by [@OP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4552537/express-highest-floating-point-quantity-that-is-less-than-1/4553339#comment4991147_4552537) in a highly portable fashion:

```
#include <float.h>
double before_1 = 1.0 - DBL_EPSILON/FLT_RADIX;
```

`DBL_EPSILON` is the absolute difference between 1.0 and the next *greater* `double`.

`FLT_RADIX` is the radix (base) of the floating point system.  Often 2.  Values like 16 and 10 have been used.